# How to access parameter in spring controller method when its called second time

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have `updateNewPassword()` in my controller which gets `hString` from request for the first time and when the second time its called I need to access `hString` again so am adding it to `ModelAndView` object mav before return statement as below but on the second call to `updateNewPassword()` am getting `hString` as null. Can someone please help me how to fix this?

Am using Spring MVC 4 and JDK 7

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView updateNewPassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
    getCurrentRequestProperties().put(CurrentRequestProperties.IS_VALID_REQUEST, true);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    String hString = request.getParameter("hString");
    String newPassword = request.getParameter("newPassword");
    String confirmPassword = request.getParameter("confirmPassword");

    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(newPassword) || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(confirmPassword)) 
    {
        UserSecurityQuestions qRecord = api.search.query(UserSecurityQuestions.class,
                api.search.property("hashString").eq(hString)).first();
        if (qRecord != null && !qRecord.isValidRequest()) 
        {
            mav.addObject("failedMessage", "forgot.url.expired");
        } 
        else 
        {
          // updates the password
         }
        } else {
        mav.addObject("hString", hString);
        mav.addObject("notimeout", true);
    }
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: "How to pass parameter to itself" - What does that mean?

Comment: @developerwjk Am sorry my question should have been more direct, I want to access the `hString` parameter in updateNewPassword() when its called for the second time but am getting it as null when its called second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> need to access hString again so am adding it to ModelAndView object
>   mav before return statement as below but on the second call to
>   updateNewPassword() am getting hString as null.

When you add it to the model . it will be available only till the current `request` is alive (i.e.) only till your view is rendered.

So it returned `null` . if you want the variable to be available in the further request , you could store it in the `session` .